# R convert time format 130800Z - Day, Hour, Min

Tags: r, datetime, time

I am calling an api that returns the time in the format `130800Z` which represents The day, hour and minutes. I'm wonder if there is an easy way to convert this?

My approach would be string splitting `Sys.Date` to get the month and year, then splitting `130800Z` by every 2 characters and merging all the results into  `2017-10-13 08:00:00`

Just wondering if there is a way to use `striptime(sprintf(...` without having to split anything?

Comment: In the `130800Z`, is it day of the year?

Comment: No day of month, hence using `Sys.date` for the other data - the api updates hourly so no issue of getting wrong month/year

Comment: Day of month, hour, min (UTC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
strptime(x = time,format = "%d%H%M",tz = "GMT")
#[1] "2017-10-13 08:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: even easier than I expected haha

Answer (score 0):

I did this but had to use splitting

`time =  "130950Z"`

```
day = substring(time, seq(1,nchar(time),2), seq(2,nchar(time),2))[1]
hour = substring(time, seq(1,nchar(time),2), seq(2,nchar(time),2))[2]
min = substring(time, seq(1,nchar(time),2), seq(2,nchar(time),2))[3]
year = unlist(str_split(Sys.Date(), "-"))[1]
month = unlist(str_split(Sys.Date(), "-"))[2]

dt = strptime(sprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", year, month, day, hour, min, 0), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

`dt =  "2017-10-13 09:50:00 GMT"`